# Why does turning on @Cacheable cause my transaction to fail?

Tags: caching, grails, rollback, spring-transactions

I have a service that I'd like to make cacheable. I've been looking into the [grails-cache plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/docs/manual/guide/usage.html) and it looks very promising, but it's causing some behavior that I don't understand.

Consider the following service:

```
class FooService {
    def contentService

    @Listener
    void processFoo(Foo foo) {
        doStuff(foo)
        foo.save(failOnError: true)
    }

    private void doStuff(Foo foo) {
        contentService.evaluate(foo.name)
    }
}
```

Now here's the `ContentService` definition:

```
class ContentService {
    Object findSource(String name) {
        Content.findByPath(name) ?: Content.findByPath(stripLocale(name))
    }

    String evaluate(String name) {
        ....
    }
}
```

This all works fine until I try to add caching. First, I set it up in Config.groovy:

```
grails.cache.config = {
    cache {
        name 'content'
    }
}
```

Then in my ContentService, I annotate my method:

```
@Cacheable('content')
Object findSource(String name) {
    Content.findByPath(name) ?: Content.findByPath(stripLocale(name))
}
```

After making these changes, my `processFoo` method successfully executes every line of code and then throws one of these on exit:

> illegal arg invokation java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException:
>   Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

What confuses me the most about this is that the method with the `@Cacheable` annotation isn't even called by my `FooService`. Only the `evaluate()` method is called, and there appear to be no issues with that method. Why would adding this annotation to a method that's not even being used in this execution cause the transaction to rollback?

Comment: Do you see the same behavior with the `grails.cache.proxyTargetClass` config option set to `true`?

Comment: @Andrew: yes, same behavior with this setting on.

Comment: @Samo Did you ever find out a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: @Thihara I do not remember!

Answer (score 0):

Do your FooService and ContentService really need to behave in a transaction?  If not, try disabling the transactional behavior of the services by adding the line below to your service classes and see if it helps:

```
static transactional = false
```